# How to enable Alt_L on Arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Currently my fresh installation of Arch linux doesn't register the `Alt_L` key press. After going through the Arch wiki, I found the `us1` keyboard layout has the option of `"linux-with-two-alt-keys"` enabled, and also includes the `us` keyboard layout.

I have a keyboard with US English qwerty layout.

I was trying to create a `personal.map` with the following:

```
include "linux-with-two-alt-keys"
```

when I tried running this file using:

```
 loadkeys /usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps/personal.map
```

The command fails with `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console.`

I also tried to change the `XkbLayout` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf`  :

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us1"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc105+inet"
        Option "XkbOptions" "caps:escape,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

But this didn't work either.

Is there anyway to handle this case so that both the alts are working with linux?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some detail. What layout does your keyboard have? How did you try to apply this other layout? How did it fail? Are you using a GUI? What GUI?

Comment: I have edited and added more details @terdon

Comment: Do you have a GUI installed? If yes, which one?

Comment: GUI for keyboards? I don't have any installed, I am using XMonad as my WM. @terdon

Comment: No, I meant GUI in general. This is Arch, so there's no GUI installed by default. Doesn't XMonad offer any Settings tool for keyboards? Have you tried `setxkbmap`?

Comment: If I am not mistaken `setxkbmap` uses the configuration in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` file? I have the file setup and it didn't work.  Maybe there is some config value I am missing? I have included the setup in the question for your reference.

Comment: I am not at all sure what it uses, you may very well be 100% correct.